# str.charAt(5) vs str[5] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

Why is the `str[3]` version so much slower, apparently?

```
var str = 'Hello';

str.charAt(3);
str[3];
```

http://jsperf.com/charat-ck

Edit: for me, `str[3]` is 80% slower on `Chrome 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 13.04`.

Comment: Depends on browser and OS, I get `str[3]` fastest by 10% in Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: fascinating. Chrome on Mac str[3] is 35% slower

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu too. That's weird. `str[3]` is 80% slower.

Comment: The `.charAt()` version is **much** slower in Firefox.

Comment: It's particularly strange since (without looking) my assumption was that charAt(int) was just a wrapper around str[int]

Comment: I don't think this is something to worry about, you'd have to test a real world application to really tell if it's worth using one or the other.

Comment: With Firefox 24.0, I got almost identical results for each. It depends on the browser, apparently. I wonder if this could be a cache issue on machines where one option performs slower than the other.

Comment: I find it's important to make sure I [*use* the value](http://jsperf.com/charat-ck/2) rather than just retrieving it. Didn't really matter much here, though. `charAt` massively wins in Chrome, `[]` in Firefox, and `[]` in IE. Not, as elclanrs pointed out, that it's likely to matter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I still get "dereference" faster by 10% in Chrome/Ubuntu .

Comment: @elclanrs: I wonder if Chrome is so fast the measurement is meaningless, since I'm also using Chrome/Ubuntu (an outdated version, though).

Comment: I think so too, the thing about these tests is that they can't show accurate results unless you test something useful.

Comment: @elclanrs: Yeah. I [threw in a 1,000-iteration loop](http://jsperf.com/charat-ck/3) but other than washing out the results a bit (because of the added overhead), my old Chrome still prefers `charAt`.

Comment: +1 to "jsperf doesn't show the real picture here". Have done several tests in Firefox, sometimes the first method was faster, sometimes the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tune the benchmark a little: http://jsperf.com/charat-ck/4

Don't use constants and no-operation code like that because it can be easily eliminated and then you aren't measuring what you think you are measuring.

Next consider that even if we have infinitely smart JIT, these operations have different semantics:

What happens when you call `charAt` out of bounds? Simply return the empty string.

What happens when you call `[]` out of bounds? Walk the prototype chain from String to Object and return `undefined` when finally not found:

```
String.prototype[3] = "hi";
var string = "asd";
string.charAt(3); //""
string[3]; //"hi"
```

It is true that it could perform the same when all reads are in-bounds however.